# Read SortedList from Hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable, sortedlist

How can I read the value from SortedList when I have this structure in Hashtable ?

Below is the example

```
public SortedList sl = new SortedList();
sl[test] = 1;
Hashtable ht= new Hashtable();
ht.Add("root", sl);
```

I want to read the `sl[test]`.

Comment: I might suggest using the generic version of SortedList: `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` and instead of HashTable using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (Although dictionary isn't a 1:1 substitution for HashTable) to avoid redundant boxing/unboxing of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do the reverse:

```
SortedList sortedList = (SortedList)ht["root"];

object value = sortedList[test];
```

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, you will need to cast the result of the hash table back to a `SortedList` before you can use methods such as the indexer on it, requiring this kind of ugliness:

```
var result = (ht["root"] as SortedList)[test];
```

However, if all elements of your hashtable are `SortedList`s, you can use a generic container such as a `Dictionary` instead, to avoid the casting:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, SortedList> { { "root", sl } };
result = dic["root"][test];
```

And you might also consider replacing the `SortedList` with its [generic counterpart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g. `SortedList<string, int>` (depending on the type of 'test'), for the same reasons.